# Java reg exp match pattern

Tags: java, xml, regex

I'm trying to use regexp to parse a string like similar to this:

```
<tag>Text that is written here. This could happen here: <Inline::~Inline> </tag>
```

How can I use regexp to replace the "<" and ">" characters from Inline. Problem is that Inline might have a different name and inside the main tag one can see comparisons such as '< 20'.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more specific concerning to different name of Inline? Is it close list of names? Is it close format, i.g. `<Something::~Something>`?

Comment: I'm not sure on the possible values, but the format is the same

Comment: In this case mark answer of user1168884 as correct because it *is*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the inline tag:

- has the same string in it twice, once preceded by a tilde
- always has the two colons

then this should work:

```
    String s= "<tag>some text here > 20 <test::~test> and then </tag>";
    s = s.replaceAll("<((\\w+)::~\\2)>","$1");
    System.out.println(s);
```

regardless what Inline/Test is called.

EDITED - forgot to put TWO colons in :-)

Comment: Regex grouping (i.e., the \\2 syntax) is pretty much the best thing since sliced bread! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since I think this is an answer worth, I write it as an answer instead of a comment:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) and of course the first [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/155137) to the question.
So, to make it clear and short: *Don't even try to use regular expressions*.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern should match any tag:

```
<(.|\n)*?>
```

So for the inline matching:

```
<Inline(.|\n)*?>
```